# multiple joins in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I am building a recipe app where a user can view recipes, list ingredients, get a shopping list, etc. etc.

Each Recipe is made of steps, each step has ingredients, and each ingredient has a grocery.

I was quite sure that the way to create these links was through the models, so my models look like this

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :steps,    :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :ingredients, :through => :steps
    has_many :groceries, :through => :ingredients
end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  has_many :ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groceries, :through => :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :step
    belongs_to :recipe
    has_one :grocery
end

class Grocery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
        has_and_belongs_to_many :steps, :through => :ingredients
        has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes, :through => :ingredients
end
```

I can output debug @recipe.steps, @recipe.ingredients, but @recipe.groceries returns

```
uninitialized constant Recipe::Grocery
```

I think this is an issue with the joins, but I don't see why I should need to specify the join in the controller.

The controller is simply

```
def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @recipe }
    end
  end
```

Am i looking for my error in the right place? or am I misinterpreting the error??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually wrote a blog post about this a while back.  The problem is that you can't daisy-chain `has_many :through` associations in Rails.  Here's a link to my article explaining it:

http://kconrails.com/2010/01/28/nesting-has_many-through-relationships-in-ruby-on-rails/

The quick answer is that you can use the [nested_has_many_through](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through) plugin to do this.  A word of caution, though - the more you chain together, the slower and more complex the database hits are going to get.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jaime, sorry for the delay in responding. I was travelling when I first asked this question, and was without internet for a few days. Then when I finally got back online I was working on a different project. I've just returned to this one. Anyway, yes, you get credit, though I had hoped there was a better solution. Good to know about these limitations.

Comment: @jaime your link is no longer valid. Do you have a new one?

Comment: If it still helps anyone, link to broken URL: https://web.archive.org/web/20160313123814/http://kconrails.com/2010/01/28/nesting-has_many-through-relationships-in-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could possibly solve your problem with a cascaded join, e.g.

```
entries = Recipe.joins(step: [ingredient: [:grocery]])
```